# Synchronization for static and non static methods

Tags: java, static, synchronization

A class has a static method and non-static method which are synchronized. Two threads are trying to access these methods, will they be able to do that? is there any lock ?what type of lock ?

Comment: Right now it is unclear what you are asking. It looks like this is Java? Add that tag. Also fix your grammar and then finally add your code.

Answer (score 2):

They will be synchronized, but on different objects, and hence there will be no protection against them both running at the same time.

An instance method is synchronized on the object instance, while a static method is synchronized on the class object.

If you want common synchronization between the two use a common lock object in synchronized clauses.  Eg, you can synch both on the class object.

Answer (score 1):

When using the word `synchronized` on a method you in fact lock `this` for instance method and the class itself of a static method.

For example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public synchronized void foo1() {}

    public synchronized void foo2() {}
}
```

In this example, only one thread can enter `foo1()` or `foo2()` of the same instance. So if we have something like this:

```
MyClass instance1 = new MyClass();
MyClass instance2 = new MyClass();
```

So it's possible for a thread to be in `foo1()` for `instance1` while another thread is in `foo1()` of `instance2`. But it's impossible for 2 threads to enter `foo1` of `instance1` **AND** `foo2` on `instance1`. Because they're both lock using `this`.

The same goes for static method, but instead, they lock on the class itself. Meaning - one thread can enter a `synchronized` static method at a certain point.

Comment: @user3117979 - It would be nice if you can accept the answer if that is so (mark the V sign next to the question)